# Bonmin installation problems

Tags: optimization, solver, pyomo

I am trying to use BONMIN solver for optimization on my Linux machine for a pyomo model. I have installed Bonmin-1.8.6 using the commands

```
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

But after this, I am unable to find the binary of bonmin. I tried the `locate bonmin` command, but all I found was the various directories and files having name Bonmin in them. Did I do something wrong at the installation step?

I also tried downloading binaries of Bonmin-1.0.1. After running the binary, it throws error that

```
error while loading shared libraries: libsvml.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

After searching about this error, I felt that is issue is regarding the compilers (gcc vs intel compilers). I also downloaded libsvml.so file available online, but it was built for 32bit system while I am working on 64bit system.

I had the same libsvml.so missing problem for Ipopt too. But I reinstalled ipopt made for gcc compilers (version-3.7.1).I have ipopt-3.7.1 installed and fully functioning. I couldn't do this for the Bonmin.
Is there any way I can solve this missing libsvml.so problem?

Thanks

Comment: You could use the binaries from the AMPL website (Pyomo works with AMPL solvers).

Comment: First of all: i also recommend going for AMPLs binaries as mentioned by Erwin. This seems like a viable route to me using pyomo (which is very much / ?completely? file + binary based). In regards to your install, it looks to me that you skipped all 3rdparty-components which are needed. The need for this is mentioned on the official page (short), but not all bonmin sources bring the 3rdparty-dir (releases should). These are usually BLAS, LAPACK, MUMPS, ASL. Now the guessing part: config will tell you; but probably it's trying to use intels VML/MKL because it can't find BLAS. Somehow this fails.

Comment: @sascha At the end of ` ./configure `, it says that the configuration is successful. Also, I think Ipopt too requires the third part libraries, which I am guessing are installed as Ipopt works fine. I will try with the AMPL binaries though. Thanks.